# Emit Flow values when the block is inside Runnable body

Tags: android, runnable, kotlin-coroutines

So I have this function where I can emit values with flow but I need to send values periodically and so I used:

```
fun hereIsAFunction(): Flow<Type> = flow {
    Handler.postDelayed({
        //This is in Runnable and I can't emit values
        emit(value) //Error 'Suspension function can only be called within Coroutine body
    }, 1000)

    usingOtherFunction()
}
```

I don't want to block the function 'usingOtherFunction()', that's why I'm using a runnable

**Question:** Is there any way to emit values with Flow with periodically events? If yes, what should I look into?

Comment: `callbackFlow` builder might be what you're looking for: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html

Comment: You want to emit something periodically, also calling `usingOtherFunction()` as parallel method?

Comment: Yes @beigirad sadly callbackFlow isn't what I'm looking for since that is a synchronized way to offer values which is not my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment that you want to do something in parallel, you can launch 2 coroutines in a scope. They will run independent to each other:

```
fun hereIsAFunction(): Flow<Type> = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            (0..100).forEach {
                delay(1000)
                emit(...)
            }
        }
        launch {
            usingOtherFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are literally big brain right now, this worked for me! There was an error about `Flow invariant is violated: Emission from another coroutine is detected.` but I solved it by just changing `= flow {` to `= channelFlow {`.  Thank you very much!

PS: The error I had is because I'm using viewModelScope.launch, which is creating another thread that's why the error happened but I didn't inform about that in the question so don't worry, everything's fine!

Answer (score 1):

Flows are built on top of coroutines.  You can use the `delay(time)` method of coroutines to delay the execution.

More details here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#create

Comment: Forgot to say I don't want to block any of the next operations which I know if use delay I'll be 'blocking' that same thread, that's why I'm using runnable

Comment: You can not use emit within a runnable. Because that code is executed in a separate thread or UI thread depending on the looper.

Comment: Flows are sequential. so you cannot switch threads or contexts within the flow.